# can strict mode be removed without side-effects

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript application and I would like to know if by removing all the "use strict;" statements in the program, I would be changing its behaviour in some way. 
As far as I understand, strict mode does not allow some stuff and once the application has finished development, I can remove it without causing any side-effects. 
There is also the case of the 'this' variable mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) but Chrome does not seem to have implemented this behaviour till now. 
Thanks!

Comment: You might want to add this to your list of related pages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

Comment: have a look to this article hope this helps http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few cases where your code may be affected, though most of them are rather contrived:

- When passing `null` or `undefined` as the `this` value (in non-strict mode this is converted to the global object, not an empty object):

  ```
  'use strict';
  (function () {
      if (!this) console.log('performs proper actions');
      else console.log('fail! oops...');
  }).call(undefined); // 'performs proper actions'
  ```

  In strict mode, this would log `"performs proper actions"`. However, this isn't the same in non-strict mode, where you'd get the failure message:

  ```
  (function () {
      if (!this) console.log('performs proper actions');
      else console.log('fail! oops...');
  }).call(undefined); // 'fail! oops...'
  ```

  It also has the same behaviour if you use `null` instead of `undefined`.
- If your function relies on the `this` value not being coerced to an object -- in non-strict mode, `this` is implicitly coerced to an object. For example, values such as `false`, `'Hello World!'`, `NaN`, `Infinity` and `1` will be coerced to their object wrapper equivalents (as mentioned before, `null` and `undefined` have their own behaviour). Compare what happens in strict mode:

  ```
  'use strict';
  (function () { console.log(this); }).call(1); // 1
  ```

  ... with what happens in non-strict mode:

  ```
  (function () { console.log(this); }).call(1); // '[object Number]'
  ```
- When relying on formal parameters and the `arguments` object not sharing their values on assignment:

  ```
  function strict(a, b, c) {
      'use strict';
      var a = 1;
      var b = 2;
      var c = 3;
      var d = 4;
      console.log('strict: ' + (arguments[0] === a ? 'same' : 'different')); // different
      console.log('strict: ' + (arguments[1] === b ? 'same' : 'different')); // different
      console.log('strict: ' + (arguments[2] === c ? 'same' : 'different')); // different
      console.log('strict: ' + (arguments[3] === d ? 'same' : 'different')); // of course they're different; by design
  }

  function notStrict(a, b, c) {
      var a = 1;
      var b = 2;
      var c = 3;
      var d = 4;
      console.log('non-strict: ' + (arguments[0] === a ? 'same' : 'different')); // same
      console.log('non-strict: ' + (arguments[1] === b ? 'same' : 'different')); // same
      console.log('non-strict: ' + (arguments[2] === c ? 'same' : 'different')); // same
      console.log('non-strict: ' + (arguments[3] === d ? 'same' : 'different')); // of course they're different; by design
  }

  strict(0, 1, 2, 3);
  notStrict(0, 1, 2, 3);
  ```

  What you get is the following:

  ```
  strict: different
  strict: different
  strict: different
  strict: different
  non-strict: same
  non-strict: same
  non-strict: same
  non-strict: different
  ```
- If you have been using `eval` and you call it directly, you'll find that variables and functions declared inside the `eval` call are leaked to the surrounding scope, instead of being in its own scope when in strict mode. For example, `a` retains its original value in strict mode:

  ```
  'use strict';
  var a = 42;
  eval('var a = -Infinity;');
  console.log(a); // 42
  ```

  ... while in non-strict mode, it is assigned a new value:

  ```
  var a = 42;
  eval('var a = -Infinity;');
  console.log(a); // -Infinity
  ```

  If you were relying on a new scope being created, this would be a breaking change to your code.
- If you deliberately use the way that a `ReferenceError` is thrown if you attempt to assign to a variable that has not been defined yet, this will affect the way your code runs:

  ```
  try {
      randomVariableThatHasntBeenDefined = 1;
  } catch (e) {
      alert('performs logic');
  }
  ```

  The alert will not be shown in non-strict mode.

All of these can be found in [Annex C](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C) of the [ECMAScript 5.1 Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/), which is the authoritative reference for what happens in each of these cases. While it isn't exactly easy reading, it can be useful to understand particular corner cases and why they behave as they do.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases strict mode just limits what the code can do, but you can't assume that removing strict mode never changes the behaviour. The use of the `arguments` array is for example different in strict mode and normal mode.

Example:

```
function test(a) {
  "strict mode";
  a = 42;
  return arguments[0];
}
```

If you call this function with `test (1337)` it will return 1337, but if you remove the strict mode from it, it would instead return 42.

For a comprehensive list of what the strict mode does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode